# Images from Database Loading Glitchy

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, cross-browser

I'm getting weird issues with ie and firefox when showing image datatypes stored in a sql server 2008 database. Before the images are finished loading/caching there are white lines that flash upwards through them. It is not how images normally load in firefox or ie, any ideas?

Comment: Are the images progressive JPEGs? Are they streaming out of the database? can you give us a code example of how you are outputting them to the browser (not HTML).

Answer (score 1):

I'd try installing something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) so you can inspect the traffic back-and-forth, then try making a request both from-database (has issue) and from-file (no issue) and compare the raw data being transferred in both cases.

I suspect you'll find some difference - perhaps a few extra characters being written to the output stream at the start or an unset mime-type or something like that. Then all you have to do is work on making the database outputted file match up as precisely as possible with the working example you have and presumably the problem will go away.

If you can't find a difference perhaps the only difference is in the load speed and it's actually progressive images, using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) once again you can simulate a slow connection speed which if it's progressive files should make it occur for the direct file downloads. If this is the case your only real option is to optimize your image delivery code as it's the delay in the serving of the file which would be causing it to be visible (Either that or just don't flush the output stream till the whole image is written - I presume the images are relatively small?).